# EF 7 - running migrations to update - already an object named 'defaultsequence' in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, orm, .net-4.6

I am trying out EF 7 migrations (using the DNX ef commands). I was able to create my initial schema, but when I made some changes to my model, created a new migration (which worked), and then tried to apply them, I got this error:

SqlException: There is already an object named 'DefaultSequence' in the database

'DefaultSequence' isn't a property I'm knowingly working with.  Any insight would be helpful, thanks!

These are the commands I was using:

dnx . ef migration Add MyMigration
dnx . ef migration apply

Comment: The name suggests that it's a Sql Server sequence object.

Comment: Why is it trying to create it again then?

Comment: Maybe related to this? https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2278